# how to replace private pem key

Tags: bash, shell

I tried to replace private.pem with cat command but I get an error.

How can I avoid this error?

■ shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

privateKey=$(cat private.pem)

replacedKey=$(awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' private.pem)
echo $replacedKey

sed -e "s|PRIVATE_KEY: .*$/PRIVATE_KEY: $(echo $replacedKey)|g" ./docker-compose.yaml
```

■ error （macOS）

```
sed: 1: "s|PRIVATE_KEY: .*$/PRIV ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use such way. Because cert key files are include "/" character which causes issue on **sed** parameter separator.
What is best practice use additional environment variable to pass to docker-compose and always replace variable content on air.

- Abother interesting way you can use `envsubst` command.

```
privateKey=$(cat private.pem)

replacedKey=$(awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' private.pem) envsubst  < docker-compose.yaml
```

Comment: thank you. I could resolve this problem.